# How to transform the series of lat long data into longest paths

Tags: python, laravel, postgresql, time-series

I'm working on geographical data in which i have millions of lat-longs with track id. this data are in a time series format. What i want is iterate all the lat long by track id, find the longest distances for specific lat long and store those data as start & end point to get the directions of each track. So, I want to convert those lat longs into multiple path with longest distance.

As of now, i am using the postgres database and Python but any relevant optimized solution would be helpfull.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? at the moment, I read multiple questions (distance calculation, database usage etc.). For example, what do you mean by "*find the longest distances for specific lat long*"? A pair of lat/lon(/time) coordinates marks one point in space (and time), so how would you calculate a *distance* from that? I think you need at least two such points...

Comment: Just my opinion on this concern, probably substituting lat long to an x,y axis, drawing if positions changes up, down, left, right based on track ID and current lat,long positions, then calculating distance between those points? That is a lot of mathematical formula needed. You might need to post this in Math Stack for assistance.

Comment: not only that, if for example during the travel, your lat,long position curve back near the starting point, should it measure the distance from start to end in the actual line or the current distance ?

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth You need to do very little math here: in Postgres, [PostGIS extension](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) has all this built-in and highly optimised. On Python side there's a similar situation with [geopandas](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/geoseries.html).

Answer (score 0):

Add the [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/documentation/getting_started/) extension, pass the coordinates to [`st_makepoint()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html) and aggregate those over time with [`st_makeline()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html). Here's a [demo:](https://dbfiddle.uk/vS8RRwI-)

```sql
create extension if not exists postgis;

create table series_of_locations_as_paths as
select track_id,
       st_makeline(st_makepoint(lon,lat) order by tstz) as track,
       min(tstz) as started,
       max(tstz) as finished
from test
group by track_id;

select track_id,
       finished-started as duration,
       st_length(track)/nullif(extract('epoch' from finished-started),0) avg_speed,
       st_astext(track)
from series_of_locations_as_paths;
```

| actor_id | st_astext | duration | avg_speed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | LINESTRING(0 0,0 1,1 1,1 2,2 2) | 04:00:00 | 0.0002777777777777778 |
| 2 | LINESTRING(0 0,0 1,0 2,0 3) | 03:00:00 | 0.0002777777777777778 |
| 3 | LINESTRING(0 0) | 00:00:00 | *null* |

To find the part of each path that spanned the longest, you can check [`st_longestline()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LongestLine.html) that fits in there, then [`st_locatepoint()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineLocatePoint.html) of the tips of that line on your path, and take a [`st_linesubstring()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineSubstring.html) based on that. This will cut out the part of the path that went this "furthest distance", connecting the extremities of the track

```sql
select track_id,
       longest_line longest_line,
         st_linesubstring(
            track
            ,least( ST_LineLocatePoint(track,a)
                   ,ST_LineLocatePoint(track,b) )
            ,greatest( ST_LineLocatePoint(track,a)
                      ,ST_LineLocatePoint(track,b) )
         ) as part_of_path_that_connected_extremities
from series_of_locations_as_paths,
lateral (select st_longestline(track,track) )as ll(longest_line),
lateral (select st_startpoint(longest_line),
                st_endpoint(longest_line) )extremities(a,b);
```

Finding how far you can go from an arbitrary point down each of those paths/tracks is a similar task: find `st_longestline()` between your point and the path:

```sql
select track_id,
       longest_line longest_line,
         st_linesubstring(
            track
            ,least( ST_LineLocatePoint(track,a)
                   ,ST_LineLocatePoint(track,b) )
            ,greatest( ST_LineLocatePoint(track,a)
                      ,ST_LineLocatePoint(track,b) )
         ) as path_reaching_furthest_away_from_point
from series_of_locations_as_paths,
lateral (select st_longestline(track,'POINT(1 3)'::geometry) 
        )as ll(longest_line),
lateral (select st_startpoint(longest_line),
                st_endpoint(longest_line) )extremities(a,b);
```

You can plot each track in different colour in [QGIS](https://qgis.org/). The dashed line over the track is the path that reaches furthest away from a custom point:

[image: paths over tracks from a point]